# Gargi’s question to Yajnavalkya Brihadaranyaka Upanishad

Tags: advaita, upanishads

In Janaka’s court Sage Yajnavalkya was questioned by his wife and student Gargi, but she refers to him by his name, Yajnavalkya, while asking the question. Is it not vedic custom to give respect and revere one’s husband and Guru? The question, I believe, is:

1. What does God (Not Demi-God) meditate on? or what brahman is supported?

> > Then she asked a final question, on what was Brahman (world of the imperishable)? Yagnavalakya put an end to the debate by telling Gargi not to proceed further as other wise she would lose her mental balance. This riposte put an end to their further dialogue at the conference of the learned.[1][15] However, at the end of the debate she conceded to the superior knowledge of Yajnavalkya by saying: "venerable Brahmins, you may consider it a great thing if you get off bowing before him. No one, I believe, will defeat him in any argument concerning Brahman
> > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargi_Vachaknavi

Ans: Yajnavalkya warns Gargi on this question because God doesn’t have another God.. Why did he warn her instead of answering?

2. I have the same question with respect to an Advaitic jivana muktha, because he realised that he is God. On what does he meditate if he doesn’t have any other god other than himself?

Comment: So there are 3 questions totally? - 1. wife respect to husband/ student to guru; 2. Why does Yajnavalkya warn instead of answering properly; 3. Whom does god and a realised person meditate on?

Comment: Yes @Archit 3 questions

Comment: 1 - you have multiple questions in 1 question. 2 - please cite the verses that you are questioning.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda requesting you not to downvote please. It would be nice if we could give the asker a suggestion and he would improve on it. Downvoting is for when something is offensive. This post is not offensive and hence not required to be dealt with by downvoting. If would be really nice if you would consider withdrawing your downvote and if improved maybe contribute an upvote instead. Thanks :)

Comment: Gargi was neither the wife nor the student of Yajnavalkya. She was another scholar who was present in Janaka's court with other scholars, when Yajnavalkya came and asked his student Samashravas to take all the cows home. Then the other scholars felt insulted that he would consider himself the best and deserving the cows. Then one by one they question him. Gargi also questions him, and they finally have a private discussion.

Comment: His point was that logic can only go so far in giving answers. If you only rely on logic, it will result in anavasthA doSha, i.e. ad infinitum. Brahman is realized through experience, not logic. The translation you have used does not capture the idiom. मूर्धा ते विपतिष्यति does not mean "she will lose her mental balance". It is an idiom. Like saying "your tongue will get burnt" or something like that. So he's saying "her head will fall off" as a sort of warning that this line of endless questioning will not give answers.

Comment: If he has realized he is Brahman, there is nothing for him to meditate on. Only when there is duality, there is something "other" than himself that he has to direct his attention.

Comment: Gargi is one of wife of yagnyavalkya  @RamAblloh that is proven  and she is know as wife during this whole debate also, yagnyavalkya if he is hiding the fact he would deemed ineligible to get the prize by other scholars

Comment: I  search for Gargu to be wife yagnyavalkya nothing is on the avail but Bannaje govindacharya during his discourse said that yagnyavalkya married Gargi his studdnt

Comment: Would be interested to see proper evidence of that. But the Upanishad text itself says that Maitreyi and Katyayani were the 2 wives. And Maitreyi received the Brahmavidya from her husband.

Comment: While leaving for Vanaprastha yagnyavalkya mentions 2 only because he wanted divide the properties betweenb 2  and Gargi is silent because he leaves with his youngest wife to Forrest